# jQuery $.getJSON resultado en blanco, JSON procesado en PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

Mi problema es el siguiente.  Puedo hacer iteraciones con objetos `JSON`. Pero cuando quiero traer los valores de un  `php` (con la consulta a mi base de datos) no me permite hacer iteraciones. Quiero tener un archivo  `php` que me muestre la consulta de la base de datos y luego con  `JSON` mostrar los valores de una fila en especifico.

Tengo este script y me funciona.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $.get("pruebauno.php",function(r,xmr){

              $("#todo5").html(r)}
              )});
```

Sin embargo. Al usar `$.getJSON` no me funciona. Coloque lo siquiente

```
<div class="todo5" id="todo5">
      <script>   $(document).ready(function(){
          var texto="";
          $.getJSON("prueba.php",function(r,responsetxt){

   $('#todo5').html(r);

                       }); 
      });


      </script>

   </div>
```

Mi php es el siguiente

```
<?php
header("charset=UTF-8");

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123" );
mysqli_select_db($conn,"manager");
$sqlappi="SELECT actividades.nombre_actividad,actividades.estado,actividades.horas,actividades.fecha,actividades.cumplimiento,usuarios.nombre AS nom, proyectos.nombre_proyecto AS pro FROM actividades LEFT JOIN usuarios on actividades.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario right JOIN proyectos on actividades.id_proyecto=proyectos.id_proyecto;";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlappi);


WHILE($datos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
echo json_encode($datos);

}

?>
```

Como verán acontinuación el resultado de mi consulta de php es un objeto json. Lo siguiente es el resultado de mi PHP. No entiendo por qué el `getJSON` no me muestra ningún valor.

```
{"nombre_actividad":"Programacion y desarollo","estado":"Terminado","horas":"160 Horas","fecha":"02 de Marz","cumplimiento":"Con retrasos","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"FEED BACK","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Lanzamiento","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Programacion y desarollo","estado":"Terminado","horas":"160 Horas","fecha":"02 de Marz","cumplimiento":"Con retrasos","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"FEED BACK","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Lanzamiento","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Seleccion de proveedores","estado":"Terminado","horas":"48 Horas","fecha":"02 de Febr","cumplimiento":"Exitoso","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Publicidad","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Eventos de apertura","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Seleccion de proveedores","estado":"Terminado","horas":"48 Horas","fecha":"02 de Febr","cumplimiento":"Exitoso","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Publicidad","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Eventos de apertura","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar los valores de la consulta con JSON. He intentado usar JSON y no me muestra ningun valor.

Intente iterar con el objeto y no me funciona. Puse

```
$('#todo5').html(r[0]);
```

y el resultado no fue lo esperado. queria que me mostrara el primer elemento del objeto y lo que hizo fue mostrarme el primer caracter, el resultado fue

```
{
```

y si coloco lo siguiente

```
 $('#todo5').html(r['estado']);
```

no me muestra ningun resultado. Lo mas normal seria que me mostrar los valores de estado del objeto

Comment: no termino de entender, en la imagen se ve que si te devuelve el json, entonces aquí cual es la duda o problema?

Comment: Por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Otra sugerencia es que siempre es mejor pegar el código en texto que colocar la imagen. Porque la imagen se puede romper y también porque con el código quienes intenten ayudarte lo pueden copiar.

Comment: cuando uso json no me devuelve ningun valor. Los valores que me devuelve son usando solamente GET. se supone que si usara getjson deberia tomar los valores. El problema es que no me funciona el GETJSON o JSON.parse

Comment: ¿Quieres `iterar` sobre tu objeto JSON para obtener los valores?

Comment: exactamente. Por ejemplo solo quiero ver los valores de "nombre_actividad:"   o de "estado". pero solo el GET no me lo permite. Por eso quiero usar el json. Ps en el php puedo crear una tabla que solo me muestre los valores de nombre actividad, pero quiero hacerlo es directamente del Js con el json. para llamar los valores de mi objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 cosas:

1. Bienvenido a SOes.
2. La pregunta está poco entendible, la pude entender gracias a los comentarios, te sugiero que al momento de redactar pienses en lo siguiente: "¿Cómo puedo dejarme entender al escribir para que la comunidad me pueda ayudar a resolver esta pregunta?", toda buena pregunta tiene un formato similar a:

   - Descripción del caso.
   - Código para poder reproducir el caso.
   - Error obtenido.
   - Resultado deseado.
   - Intentos realizados sin éxito.
3. La MDN, y toda la documentación oficial de cualquier tecnología que quieras aprender serán tus nuevas biblias.
4. Te dejo un ejemplo para que aprendas a iterar elementos dentro de un json, es cosa que sigas la documentación y mires el ejemplo, he tratado que sea lo más sencillo y directo posible.

Por cierto, lectura obligatoria:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Y no me digas que te limita que esté en otro idioma, traductores existen :) te recomiendo este en particular: https://www.deepl.com/translator

Dale click en el botón ejecutar debajo del código.

```js
var misDatosJSON =  [
  {
    "id": "5c662141b44915006533f26d",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "c29f0c86-798e-4a81-9b6c-040925c8b01f",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,003.36",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Randolph Rodriguez",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "KYAGORO",
    "email": "randolphrodriguez@kyagoro.com",
    "phone": "+1 (988) 475-3813",
    "address": "605 Sutton Street, Goodville, Massachusetts, 2881",
    "about": "Voluptate eiusmod pariatur voluptate Lorem nulla exercitation. Id cupidatat magna veniam culpa quis deserunt irure proident magna esse fugiat dolore. Esse sit nisi excepteur ea irure adipisicing eiusmod ex minim mollit ea velit voluptate. Ullamco irure ullamco veniam consectetur pariatur. Tempor ex ea sint sit deserunt id. Nostrud dolore fugiat et ut tempor adipisicing quis consectetur fugiat tempor tempor. In est duis esse sunt magna et nisi ut anim eiusmod id et.\r\n",
    "registered": "2016-04-10T11:50:08 +07:00",
    "latitude": -86.477042,
    "longitude": -89.27628,
    "tags": [
      "sit",
      "nisi",
      "mollit",
      "veniam",
      "velit",
      "qui",
      "nisi"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Dickson Bentley"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Livingston Pruitt"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jaclyn Russell"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Randolph Rodriguez! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621413514ece26b88141e",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "30030aaa-e918-493d-a3c7-834705f51652",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,083.07",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 38,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Marisol Barlow",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "PAWNAGRA",
    "email": "marisolbarlow@pawnagra.com",
    "phone": "+1 (894) 486-2695",
    "address": "410 Malbone Street, Ruckersville, Georgia, 5898",
    "about": "Aliqua non esse est commodo ullamco eiusmod anim nostrud ea adipisicing enim fugiat. Nulla fugiat elit reprehenderit reprehenderit proident. Incididunt qui est mollit irure ea duis nisi labore in fugiat occaecat occaecat consectetur. Ad tempor laborum excepteur anim ipsum exercitation nulla. Et aliquip mollit consequat ad. Elit ea tempor commodo commodo ea deserunt voluptate nulla non nostrud aliqua veniam.\r\n",
    "registered": "2015-03-10T02:12:43 +07:00",
    "latitude": -12.992765,
    "longitude": -109.547559,
    "tags": [
      "sint",
      "labore",
      "mollit",
      "magna",
      "aute",
      "enim",
      "adipisicing"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Monica Hays"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lesley Sparks"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Richardson Mcintosh"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Marisol Barlow! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621414f5788ddbbd625ea",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "9a8c0ae7-2410-49b2-b1b5-e9120803c100",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,197.73",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": "Tricia Boyd",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "KEGULAR",
    "email": "triciaboyd@kegular.com",
    "phone": "+1 (887) 410-2547",
    "address": "501 Bradford Street, Kent, New Mexico, 8088",
    "about": "Ullamco fugiat nisi esse ad pariatur amet consequat quis eiusmod minim quis. Anim nostrud amet veniam ullamco ipsum ad ut consectetur pariatur. Et officia ex nulla consectetur elit. Consectetur occaecat quis duis officia aliquip duis non enim cillum id non.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-10-06T03:15:53 +07:00",
    "latitude": 16.77847,
    "longitude": 4.794487,
    "tags": [
      "eiusmod",
      "aute",
      "aliquip",
      "enim",
      "irure",
      "est",
      "eiusmod"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 90,
        "name": "Gonzalez Witt"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Wooten Golden"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Natalia Brock"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Tricia Boyd! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621410df7cdb6ef509baf",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "88a410e5-ce5a-4f84-bc04-a0b38f2d6db4",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,989.32",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 37,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Maldonado Riddle",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "MOTOVATE",
    "email": "maldonadoriddle@motovate.com",
    "phone": "+1 (929) 575-3519",
    "address": "240 Noll Street, Robinson, South Carolina, 9212",
    "about": "Commodo aute ex Lorem voluptate consectetur quis aliqua tempor. Laboris anim qui incididunt enim velit fugiat qui irure. Dolor ea consectetur dolore dolore id id laboris excepteur. Anim tempor pariatur amet minim ad ullamco cupidatat eiusmod amet veniam sunt elit mollit cupidatat. Veniam eiusmod tempor do non excepteur velit aliquip laborum non id velit ad. Officia sint ex enim eiusmod elit aute occaecat laborum.\r\n",
    "registered": "2014-10-05T04:57:52 +07:00",
    "latitude": -62.331829,
    "longitude": 157.055853,
    "tags": [
      "Lorem",
      "eiusmod",
      "aliquip",
      "anim",
      "dolor",
      "occaecat",
      "mollit"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Patsy Sweet"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Jennings Berg"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "White Mcclain"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Maldonado Riddle! You have 3 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c662141ba3d97af0998e9a4",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "ac508b64-8cce-464c-ad33-7351decfb177",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,244.12",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 27,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Bates Arnold",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "ZILLA",
    "email": "batesarnold@zilla.com",
    "phone": "+1 (877) 544-3622",
    "address": "320 Garden Place, Itmann, Missouri, 1439",
    "about": "Sit dolore mollit tempor ad occaecat nisi sunt dolore dolore deserunt consequat magna reprehenderit ullamco. Eu fugiat proident adipisicing aliqua ex velit sunt in. Incididunt anim nostrud id Lorem nulla quis tempor sunt aliquip. Occaecat sint mollit cupidatat ex dolore laborum sint ipsum laborum nostrud. Officia aliqua velit dolor duis sint ad laborum qui do. Officia mollit do in pariatur ex pariatur labore officia. Irure excepteur in proident do ea ea fugiat.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-03-25T02:36:07 +07:00",
    "latitude": -43.415912,
    "longitude": -10.406856,
    "tags": [
      "eiusmod",
      "incididunt",
      "duis",
      "aliquip",
      "officia",
      "adipisicing",
      "commodo"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Blanca Long"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Cathryn Williams"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Mckenzie Gilbert"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Bates Arnold! You have 10 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  },
  {
    "id": "5c6621411abbefcd45dbc56e",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "b5331792-0e39-4b3d-9c40-5882f4b7f2ed",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,048.07",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Foreman Bell",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "YOGASM",
    "email": "foremanbell@yogasm.com",
    "phone": "+1 (979) 507-3435",
    "address": "494 Dakota Place, Makena, Louisiana, 4500",
    "about": "Quis sunt ullamco enim enim dolore adipisicing aliqua voluptate ad Lorem eiusmod. Minim occaecat aliqua pariatur culpa aliquip duis. Deserunt cillum sunt reprehenderit laboris ad esse magna anim ullamco aute nisi nisi qui. Aliquip anim mollit reprehenderit id esse nisi deserunt deserunt aliqua nisi id elit ipsum. Ea laboris commodo voluptate commodo occaecat sunt do tempor anim enim sit duis elit. Mollit tempor magna qui consequat aute amet sunt officia mollit ea nostrud ea nisi.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-03-20T11:17:25 +07:00",
    "latitude": -50.618937,
    "longitude": -76.141147,
    "tags": [
      "occaecat",
      "dolore",
      "magna",
      "do",
      "voluptate",
      "sit",
      "pariatur"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Iris Rollins"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Lindsey Perkins"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "Woodard Mercer"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Foreman Bell! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
];

$.each(misDatosJSON, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value.id );
  console.log("Hola usuario: " + value.name);
  console.log("Sus amigos son: ");
  $.each(value.friends, function(indiceAmigos, valorAmigos){
   console.log(indiceAmigos + ":  codigo: " +  valorAmigos.id + " "+ valorAmigos.name);
  })
  console.log("----------------");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Actualización importante**

Luego de ver el Json generado, ahí es donde se ubica el problema:

Copia el siguiente JSON:

```
{"nombre_actividad":"Programacion y desarollo","estado":"Terminado","horas":"160 Horas","fecha":"02 de Marz","cumplimiento":"Con retrasos","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"FEED BACK","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Lanzamiento","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Programacion y desarollo","estado":"Terminado","horas":"160 Horas","fecha":"02 de Marz","cumplimiento":"Con retrasos","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"FEED BACK","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Lanzamiento","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Seleccion de proveedores","estado":"Terminado","horas":"48 Horas","fecha":"02 de Febr","cumplimiento":"Exitoso","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Publicidad","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Eventos de apertura","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Seleccion de proveedores","estado":"Terminado","horas":"48 Horas","fecha":"02 de Febr","cumplimiento":"Exitoso","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Publicidad","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Eventos de apertura","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}
```

Ahora utiliza algún servicio de internet para poner un estilo "amigable" y legible a la vista humana, en este caso utilicé: https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print

Dicho servicio generó un error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
...Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Analizando tu código PHP me doy con la sorpresa que no genera un arreglo, sino que a cada objeto le va imprimiendo mediante un `echo`

```
<?php
  header("charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123" );
  mysqli_select_db($conn,"manager");
  $sqlappi="SELECT actividades.nombre_actividad,actividades.estado,actividades.horas,actividades.fecha,actividades.cumplimiento,usuarios.nombre AS nom, proyectos.nombre_proyecto AS pro FROM actividades LEFT JOIN usuarios on actividades.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario right JOIN proyectos on actividades.id_proyecto=proyectos.id_proyecto;";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlappi);

  WHILE($datos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo json_encode($datos); //Aqui el problema
  }

?>
```

Para solucionarlo, necesitas un ligero cambio, revisa los comentarios dentro del código:

```
<?php
  header("charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123" );
  mysqli_select_db($conn,"manager");
  $sqlappi="SELECT actividades.nombre_actividad,actividades.estado,actividades.horas,actividades.fecha,actividades.cumplimiento,usuarios.nombre AS nom, proyectos.nombre_proyecto AS pro FROM actividades LEFT JOIN usuarios on actividades.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario right JOIN proyectos on actividades.id_proyecto=proyectos.id_proyecto;";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlappi);
  //Arreglo donde va a contener el resultado de la query.
  $arregloDelResultado = array();
  //Reemplaza $datos por $row para que tengas la idea constante en el C:\erebro que se trata de FILAS que se recorren.
  WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $arregloDelResultado[] = $row;    
  }
  //Ahora sí, finalmente que tienes el arregloDelResultado completo, a éste le das un formato JSON
  echo json_encode($arregloDelResultado);

?>
```

Con las modificaciones en el PHP, usar jQuery o cualquier otro framework/lenguaje que permita procesar JSON, va a funcionar.

PD: Para quienes están iniciando en el sitio, vean la importancia de poner código en lugar de imágenes :D

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. De hecho antes de colocar la pregunta estuve leyendo uno de los articulos que me recomendaste.  De hecho practique un ejemplo similar al que publicaste. Pero mi problema es que quiero capturar un valor con $.getjson.   siendo la url un archivo de php.  He probado con varios ejemplos y por mas que quiero .$getjson no funciona.   Te explico un poco mas lo que estoy haciendo. Desde el php estoy mostrando los valores de una tabla del servidor mysql.  Luego con JQUERY pongo $.get() y me muestra los valores . pero al usar $.getjson no funciona para nada.

Comment: @JonathanDiaz edita tu pregunta y pega el JSON reemplazando la imagen que tienes. por otro lado, es importante las mayúsculas en el nombre del método: `$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {`

Comment: Ok. En un momento editare y colocare todo el codigo que tengo

Comment: @JonathanDiaz respuesta actualizada, el problema estaba en el PHP que no mostrarse en un inicio, por eso es importante redactar el escenario lo más completo posible para que quienes queremos solucionar, podamos reproducir los pasos :D

Comment: muchas gracias. JAJAJA tienes buen sentido del humor. Lo que paso es que en los manuales que leí todos cometían el mismo error.  Me estaba volviendo loco buscando una solución.

Comment: HAHAHA de nada hermano, estamos para servir, te recomiendo marcar la respuesta como aceptada (check al costado de la respuesta) para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio. El detalle principal es que cuando uno inicia a programar, ignora cuestionar lo que está realizando por seguir un tutorial que muestra que "sí funciona", ésto se debe a que confían en su totalidad lo que ven, por eso hay que tener los fundamentos de programación lo más sólido posible, en este caso, toda la solución vino a partir de dar formato a un JSON xD!!!

Comment: Es cosa de entrar en modo detective y realizar tantas preguntas como sean posible, de tal manera que alguna pregunta te de una pista para lograr resolver el caso, llevo años programando, aunque dejé PHP hace años, me da gusto poder ayudar :D

Comment: Probe cambiando el codigo php. y no me genera ninguna respuesta, No me muestra nada.  Ni el php ni el Get me muestran algun valor. la pagina queda en blanco

Comment: hey @JonathanDiaz ubícame por twitter, con 25 puntos de reputación en SOes puedes ir a la sala de chat, debería funcionar la respuesta que te he dado.

Comment: Ok. Te voy a escribir en twitter.

Comment: Pude resolver el problema.  Modifique el código php como lo indico fredyfx. Luego modifique la consulta a la base de datos y problema solucionado. Se ejecuta el objeto ajax con los valores de mi consulta