# $.getJSON en JQUERY me arroja resultado en blanco. Como funciona realmente JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hace poco publique una pregunta respecto a este tema. Dejo el enlace [DAME CLICK](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238013/jquery-getjson-resultado-en-blanco-json-procesado-en-php/238021?noredirect=1#comment443290_238021). Sin embargo, No encuentro la forma que `$.getJSON`  me genere algún resultado.

**

> QUE QUIERO? saber como hacer que $.getJSON me muestre el resultado de
>   un php

**

Al usar $GET  no me genera ningun problema. Me muestra el resultado de mi búsqueda que tengo en un archivo php.

Mi php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
header("charset=UTF-8");

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123" );
mysqli_select_db($conn,"manager");
$sqlappi="SELECT actividades.nombre_actividad,actividades.estado,actividades.horas,actividades.fecha,actividades.cumplimiento,usuarios.nombre AS nom, proyectos.nombre_proyecto AS pro FROM actividades LEFT JOIN usuarios on actividades.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario right JOIN proyectos on actividades.id_proyecto=proyectos.id_proyecto;";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlappi);

WHILE($datos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
echo json_encode($datos);
    }

?>
```

Este php me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
{"nombre_actividad":"Programacion y desarollo","estado":"Terminado","horas":"160 Horas","fecha":"02 de Marz","cumplimiento":"Con retrasos","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"FEED BACK","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Lanzamiento","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Programacion y desarollo","estado":"Terminado","horas":"160 Horas","fecha":"02 de Marz","cumplimiento":"Con retrasos","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"FEED BACK","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Lanzamiento","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Plataforma digital"}{"nombre_actividad":"Seleccion de proveedores","estado":"Terminado","horas":"48 Horas","fecha":"02 de Febr","cumplimiento":"Exitoso","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Publicidad","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Eventos de apertura","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Jonathan","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Seleccion de proveedores","estado":"Terminado","horas":"48 Horas","fecha":"02 de Febr","cumplimiento":"Exitoso","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Publicidad","estado":"En proceso","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"15 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}{"nombre_actividad":"Eventos de apertura","estado":"En espera","horas":"80 Horas","fecha":"30 de Marz","cumplimiento":"En espera","nom":"Judith","pro":"Apertura de tienda en Paris"}
```

Mi Get funciona a la perfeccion.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $.get("pruebauno.php",function(r,xmr){

              $("#todo5").html(r)}
              )});
```

Sin embargo, al usar get.JSON  no me funciona. No me da ningun valor. puse el siguiente codigo

```
<div class="todo5" id="todo5">
      <script>   $(document).ready(function(){
          var texto="";
          $.getJSON("prueba.php",function(r,responsetxt){

   $('#todo5').html(r);

                       }); 
      });


      </script>

   </div>
```

Quiero saber como usar el codigo getJSON.

Una persona de la comunidad me recomendo modificar el php de la siguiente forma, pero no me muestra ningun resultado

```
<?php
  header("charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123" );
  mysqli_select_db($conn,"manager");
  $sqlappi="SELECT actividades.nombre_actividad,actividades.estado,actividades.horas,actividades.fecha,actividades.cumplimiento,usuarios.nombre AS nom, proyectos.nombre_proyecto AS pro FROM actividades LEFT JOIN usuarios on actividades.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario right JOIN proyectos on actividades.id_proyecto=proyectos.id_proyecto;";
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlappi);
  //Arreglo donde va a contener el resultado de la query.
  $arregloDelResultado = array();
  //Reemplaza $datos por $row para que tengas la idea constante en el C:\erebro que se trata de FILAS que se recorren.
  WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $arregloDelResultado [] = $row;    
  }
  //Ahora sí, finalmente que tienes el arregloDelResultado completo, a éste le das un formato JSON
  echo json_encode($arregloDelResultado );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas mostrar, que te funciona con el `$.get`, no es un `J́SON` válido, lo puede verificar [aquí](https://jsonlint.com/), por eso `$.getJSON` no te devuelve nada, al parsearlo se convierte en `null`.

**$.getJSON**

> Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.
>
> ***Fuente***: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Es decir, se realizar una llamada `GET HTTP` (igual que `$.get`) y se cargaran datos **codificados en formato JSON** por lo tanto, si lo que recibe la función no es un formato válido, el resultado será inevitablemente `NULL`.

**JSON**

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation - Notación de Objetos de JavaScript)
>   es un formato ligero de intercambio de datos. Leerlo y escribirlo es
>   simple para humanos, mientras que para las máquinas es simple
>   interpretarlo y generarlo. Está basado en un subconjunto del Lenguaje
>   de Programación JavaScript, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - Diciembre
>   1999. JSON es un formato de texto que es completamente independiente del lenguaje pero utiliza convenciones que son ampliamente conocidos
>   por los programadores de la familia de lenguajes C, incluyendo C, C++,
>   C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, y muchos otros. Estas propiedades
>   hacen que JSON sea un lenguaje ideal para el intercambio de datos.
>
> JSON está constituído por dos estructuras:
>
> - Una colección de pares de nombre/valor. En varios lenguajes esto es    conocido como un objeto, registro, estructura, diccionario, tabla
>     hash, lista de claves o un arreglo asociativo.
> - Una lista ordenada de valores. En la mayoría de los lenguajes, esto    se implementa como arreglos, vectores, listas o sequencias.
>
> ***Fuente***: https://www.json.org/json-es.html

Por lo tanto como puede ver, `$.getJSON` es tan solo una variante de [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) con el **dataType** configurado como json (sus valores posibles son: xml, html, script, json, jsonp y text).

Realmente puedes hacer llamadas `$.get` y despues parsear tu mismo el resultado con  [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

---

El código que te pasaron tiene buena pinta, deberías sacar el resultado por pantalla y verificar que es un [JSON válido](https://jsonlint.com/), quizá tengas algún `warning`de php que está corrompiendo el resultado, yo te recomendaría:

- Usar `header('Content-Type: application/json');`.
- Eliminar la `?`   de cierre,  es mejor no usarla.
- Poner [`ob_claean()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-clean.php) antes del `echo` final, aunque es "peligroso" usarlo pues ocultarás posibles errores, ya que elimina el buffer de salida actual.
- Revisar el log de errores.