# Error con bind_param en PHP usando AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Necesito realizar una consulta a la BD en Mysql pero siempre obtengo este error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Y este sería el codigo.

Aquí presiono un boton llamado Actualizar.

```
'use stric'
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
        obj = { "table":"solicitudes" };
        dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                for (x in myObj) {
                  txt += myObj[x].name + "<br>";
                }
                $("#request").innerHTML = txt;
              }
            };
xhr.open("POST", "php/Spend.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("x=" + dbParam);
    });
});
```

En la consola obtengo el mismo error que en PHP "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" indica que el error esta en la línea: `myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` entiendo que lo entrega por que es la respuesta de PHP. Aqui el codigo de PHP.

```
<?php   
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_POST["x"], false);
print_r($obj);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "BD");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `titulo_solicitud` FROM ? ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $obj->table);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);


$conn->close(); ?>
```

Y esta es la respuesta del servidor en la consola de desarrollador:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [table] => solicitudes
)
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sf/php/Spend.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/sf/php/Spend.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

La línea 8 es `$stmt->bind_param("s", $obj->table);` No entiendo en donde esta el error de sintaxis

Comment: ¿Por qué emplear `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` si usas `Jquery` ?

Comment: Por que tampoco pude hacer que que php me regresara los datos como un objeto.  

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248983/recibir-datos-de-php-con-ajax/248995#248995

Ya llevo algunos dias con este problema :/

Comment: tu escenario se parece mucho a este otro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/238021/822

Comment: Si, es muy similar estoy intentando las respuesta de los comentarios y espero que ahora si el json_encode me genere el objeto de mi array por que fui ahí donde me estanque la vez anterior

Answer (score 0):

debes hacerlo asi:

tu error esta en la query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `titulo_solicitud` FROM ? ");
```

no especificaste la `tabla` ni tampoco el `campo`
`bind_param` solo funciona con nombres de `columnas` no con nombres de `tabla`.

**puedes hacer esto:**

```
//nombres de tablas permitidos evita cualquier problema
$table_allow["tabla","tabla1","tabla2","tabla3"];
//filtramos el string
$table= filter_var($obj->table, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//evita acceder a tablas que no este permitidas
if(in_array($table,$table_allow)){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `titulo_solicitud` FROM {$table}");
    $stmt->execute();
    $out =[];
    while($row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $out[]=$row["titulo_solicitud"];
    }
  echo json_encode($outp,true);
}
```

javascript cambios:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               txt="";
                myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                for (let x of myObj) {
                  txt += `${x}<br>`;
                }
                $("#request").innerHTML = txt;
              }
```

Comment: Lo ordene de esta manera

`$table= filter_var($obj->table, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT titulo_solicitud FROM {$table}");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$obj->$table);`

y ahora obtengo esto

mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: no puedes usar `bind_param()` ya que no estas pasando parametros = nombres de columnas.............. en terminos simples elimina esa linea!

Comment: Ya obtuve el array pero el json_encode no me genera el objeto json que necesito para JS

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248983/recibir-datos-de-php-con-ajax/248995#248995

Comment: Byro, esto puede prestarse a confusión: *«bind_param solo funciona con nombres de columnas no con nombres de tabla.»* Realmente funciona con **valores**, o sea lo que se pasa son los valores correspondientes a cada columna. Si intentas sustituir el **nombre** columna en sí usando `bind_param` tampoco será permitido, porque esta función es para pasar **valores** no nombres de tablas o de columnas.

Comment: Hola!! Ya lo resolví, el problema esta en la BD tenía acentos en algunos registros, aunque esta configurado con UTF-8 que tengo entendido que acepta acentos, genera algunos errores en el json_encode(); Amigo muchas gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo el ejemplo que me pusiste si me funciono al final.